# Clean up if statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-cleanup

I do have jQuery and wouldn't mind using it but here's the code I would like to clean up:

```
if (parent.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.data == null) {
    parent.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.data = new app.newData();
}
```

The only way I know how to clean it up is:

```
var data = parent.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.data;
if (data == null) { data = new app.newData()}
```

I have always wondered if there was a way to do something like:

```
parent.uglyChild.data = parent.uglyChild.data.isNull ? return : new app.newData();
```

I can't wait to see the shorthand tricks you guys know! :)

Comment: What are the objects involved here? DOM nodes or just plain objects?

Comment: You got it in step 2 - no further *"tricks"*.

Comment: @Emissary except it won't work :)

Comment: @Pointy - I figured it was a typo as it's clearly pseudo :)

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are there always 4 children? (Nod@Pointy) Is this a series of objects or is this a set of DOM elements?

Comment: I'm using objects in VS2013 LightSwitch, they're internal objects, not DOM nodes as far as I know. I traditionally use c# this LightSwitch stuff is madness to me but I'm loving javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Question should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I didn't want my code "reviewed," I was looking for "new" code, would that still be the correct place?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
var ugly = parent.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild;
ugly.data == null && (ugly.data = value)
```

Comment: Oh durr; sorry guys :)

Comment: How/why does this work?

Comment: @borkith It's called a Guard Operator. Check out this article. http://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators

Comment: Thank you for this. This will have a huge impact on my work! Will data get reassigned to value each time this is run?

Comment: Answering my own question, no. Perfect! Only if the first condition is true does it continue to the next.

Comment: You got it. You can also do something like this. 
var thing = undefined;
var newThing = thing || 'woo';

newThing will not equal 'woo' since thing was undefined.

Answer (score 1):

you can cache the nearest object to avoid repetition, thanks to JS's leaky assignments:

```
if ( (x=parent.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild.uglyChild).data == null) {
   x.data = value;
}
```

Comment: you'd want to use `var x` though.

Comment: @Emissary just saw your comment, I was asking about that

Comment: I agree, i was just showing the mechanics...

Comment: @borkith: As said, You should use a "var x" somewhere in the code that runs all this. If you don't, you create an explicit global.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I can't one up you yet. "Reputation" limits, sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ternary operator, you could always reassign the value.

`parent.uglyChild.data = (parent.uglyChild.data == null) ? null : value;`

Comment: That's both longer and less efficient than `if (parent.uglyChild.data == null) parent.uglyChild.data = value` since it *always* assigns.

Comment: Ahhh. In my case, value is a new object. I should edit that in because this would reassign the existing data to a new object.

Comment: @borkith he means it will always do an assignment, even if it is already `null`.